# PyTorch-YOLOv3 Accuracy Metrics

Tags: python, computer-vision, yolo

I'm using an existing PyTorch-YOLOv3 architecture and training it to recognize a custom dataset through google colab for a research manuscript.  Basically I want to use the object detection algorithm to count the number of objects for two classes in an image.

I've been told that for my purpose, I should generate validation/training curves for the model and create a confusion matrix to evaluate the classifier element of the trained model.  I have an idea to modify the training script to output training metrics to a csv file during the training, but I'm not familiar with how to create a confusion matrix to evaluate the trained model.

Additionally, in the field of computer vision, what kind of metrics/figures should be generated for a manuscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the first part of your question, since you seem to only be concerned with two classes, a simple confusion matrix would look like

```
         class_1   class_2
class_1    a_11      a_12
class_2    a_21      a_22
```

where `a_ij` is the number of objects of class `i` that are classified as class `j`. Ideally, you want this matrix to be diagonal.

Regarding the second part, this depends on what you are trying to show. The usual metrics for object detection are the IOU and mAP. Assuming you have a ground truth bounding box G and a detection D, you can trivially define its IOU (i.e. intersection over union) 
 as `intersection(D,G)/union(D,G)` with in intersection and union the usual operations on sets. The definition of mAP (mean average precision) varies a lot from dataset to dataset and from author to author, but usually is very close to "area under the precision-recall curve". I invite you to have a look at the Pascal or Coco dataset documentations for a thorough discussion on the subject.